# Character table-based searcher doesn't work

Tags: c, string

The following code is supposed to return the character that is registered in the table `set` and has been determined in the source string.

```
int find (char source[], char set[])
{
    int i, l = strlen(set);
    int exit = 0;

    for(i = 0; source[i] != '\0';)
    {
        do
        { 
            if(source[i] == set[l])
            { 
                exit = 1;
                break; 
            } 
            else l--; 
        } while (!l);
        if(exit) 
           break;
        else 
        { 
              i++; 
              l = strlen(set);
        }
    }

    return set[l];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you notice the return type is `int` and you're returning a `char`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: returning a `char` from a function declared to return `int` isn't a major problem; `char` will be promoted to `int` without any problem.

Comment: Just like I thought.

Comment: Please use a few more lines.  The if/else in the do/while loop should be split over multiple lines.  The if/else after the do/while should be spread over multiple lines.  The code is hard to read — unecessarily hard to read — when written like that.

Comment: Are you trying to search an charecter in the set array ? , if yes then  you can use an already builtin function strchr which gives you the first occurence of charecter in the string .

Comment: Yes. I would use `strchr` but why is my function not working? Leaving it like so and replacing what I want with standard function is a bad practice.

Comment: @AlanSalios Check the updated solution in my anser, hope your code will work now. :-)

Comment: It works. Thats why I voted up :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use early returns when appropriate, use `for` loops with all three clauses most of the time, avoid calling `strlen()` more than once, and avoid `do … while` loops.

```
int find(char source[], char set[])
{
    int len = strlen(set);

    for (int i = 0; source[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < len; l++)
        {
            if (source[i] == set[l])
                return (unsigned char)set[l];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The cast returns a positive value even if plain `char` is a signed type.

I'm not wholly convinced that returning the character is best; the index where the character is found might be better.

---

If you're stuck with a C89 compiler, then you can use:

```
int find(char source[], char set[])
{
    int len = strlen(set);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; source[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        int l;
        for (l = 0; l < len; l++)
        {
            if (source[i] == set[l])
                return (unsigned char)set[l];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I'm letting the compiler optimize `source[i]` in the inner loop.  If you don't trust your compiler, you could use:

```
int find(char source[], char set[])
{
    int len = strlen(set);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; source[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        char c = source[i];
        int l;
        for (l = 0; l < len; l++)
        {
            if (c == set[l])
                return (unsigned char)set[l];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

If you want to use a standard function, you probably want `strcspn()`, a much-neglected part of Standard C.  This will return 0 (or `'\0'`) if there is no other match, unlike the other functions that return `-1`.

```
int find(char source[], char set[])
{
    size_t i = strcspn(source, set);
    return (unsigned char)source[i];
}
```

If the negative return is important, then you'd use:

```
int find(char source[], char set[])
{
    size_t i = strcspn(source, set);
    return (source[i] == '\0') ? -1 : (unsigned char)source[i];
}
```

Or you could use `strpbrk()`:

```
int find(char source[], char set[])
{
    char *tgt = strpbrk(source, set);
    if (tgt == 0)
        return -1;
    return (unsigned char)*tgt;
}
```

And there are probably other variants I've not thought of.

If you want to keep the inner do/while loop (thus fixing up the original logic) you can write:

```
int find(char source[], char set[])
{
    int i;
    int len = strlen(set) - 1;

    for (i = 0; source[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        int l = len;
        do
        { 
            if (source[i] == set[l])
                return (unsigned char)set[l];
        } while (--l >= 0);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This avoids testing `set[strlen(set)]`, which is by definition `'\0'`, with `source[i]` which is known not to be `'\0'`.  It still uses an early return which radically simplifies the code (no `exit` variable, which is not a good name to use since there's a standard function `exit()` too).  Note, too, how this keeps the loop control for the variable `i` all in the `for` statement — that is one of its principal virtues.  You should aim to use it whenever possible.  Note that the original code scans from the end of `set` to the beginning instead of from the beginning to the end.  Both methods work essentially equally well, but starting at the beginning and ending at the end is the more conventional way to work.  It is also less apt to create bugs.  If someone changes the type of `l` to `size_t`, then it never goes negative, so the do/while variant fails.  The original proposed version will work fine if every `int` in the body of the function is changed to `size_t`.

Comment: Variable declaring in the loop body is C++-specific though.

Comment: @AlanSalios: Variable declarations in the loop initialiser are part of C since C99.

Comment: They're standard in C99 and C11, but if you're stuck with Microsoft's C compiler, then you have to declare the loop variables outside the loop.

Comment: Yes. And in C++ since C++98. No I am using gnu's which will optimize it.. I am just stating out this for portability..

Comment: I code to the 15-year old standard most of the time, and the 4-year old standard the rest of the time.  I assume that sane people are not stuck conforming to the 25-year old standard.

Answer (score 3):

I think, instead of

```
while (!l);
```

what you want is

<del>while (l);</del>

```
   while (l > -1);         //yeah, because array index starts from 0.
```

because you are decrementing the value of `l` and want to continue looping untill `l` becomes less than `0`, right?

Also, return type of function `find()` is `int` and you're returning a `char`. Even it is not an *error*, you may probably want to change that.

Comment: Right. I aways get confused of the right condition I have to place in loops. However it still doesn't work. It returns 0

Comment: @AlanSalios well, here's a hint: what if none of the `char`s in `set` match any of those in `source`?

Comment: Well I test them with the `source` `"Hello + World"` and the `set` of `"+-*/"`

Comment: @AlanSalios My bad. All about indexing. We were not testing the 1st element itself. Updated. Try now.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sir, i think by `doesn't reset l when i is incremented` you meant the skipping of index 0 at end, right? I overlooked that part, updated now, thanks :-)

Comment: Actually, I was about to delete that comment of mine (and, I have just done so); there is code at the end of the loop that increments `i` and resets `l`.  It's slow because it recomputes the length of `set` on each iteration, but it isn't the problem I thought it was.  I'm not sure it is correct, but it wasn't the problem I thought I saw.  I'm not keen on the do/while loop even so, or the disjointed loop controls (especially on the outer loop).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sir, no doubt your approach is much cleaner. I was trying to spot and fix the issue with OP's logic. :-)

Comment: Yes. He recoded everything. That doesn't really answers the question rather then providing me a nice alternative. So anyway.

Comment: @AlanSalios I'm not sure sir, what do you mean?

Comment: @AlanSalios Never mind, ignore it. I misread `re-coded` as `recorded`. Time for new specs...:-) Cheers, BTW !!!